# Alternative for "pedantic"

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like an alternative for the word "pedantic". "Pedantic" has the meaning of :

> highly concerned with minute details or formalisms, especially in learning or teaching.

The problem is, "pedantic" is used in a negative way, that is, it is used for some one who is "ostentatious, and overly concerned". I would like to have a word that has the same meaning as this word(concerned with minute details), *minus* the negative connotations.

Some come to mind:

- *meticulous*, but "meticulous" can also be used for habits, such as meticulous habits in tidiness etc.
- *scholarly*, but "scholarly" although used for study, does not necessarily have the connotation of highly meticulous study. It can just be study of a subject, without going in-depth.

Ideas please?

Comment: I think being a pedant is also awesome, nit-picking missing or incorrect details of people's works to perfecting them is definitely a positive point but to laughing at them is a noted converse. It's normal to see mixed cultures with different types of people tend to favor the latter. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedantic. Just my personal view (maybe very incorrect)

Comment: punctilious is a good word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to say that *pedantic* has more than a negative connotation. When I think of a word with a negative connotation, it's a word that has a neutral definition but tends to be interpreted as negative. *Pedantic*, on the other hand, is already a negative word by definition -- it has a negative denotation, and being *pedantic* can never be interpreted as a positive.

...Was that aside a little pedantic?

To get back on topic, the word I would use is ***[precise](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/precise)*** or *[**thorough**](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/thorough)*.
Being *precise*, *concise*, yet still *thorough* in describing something is quite the talent.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with other suggestions - especially *Meticulous*, and I'll add

> Diligent

for some contexts.

Answer (score 4):

> Meticulous, painstaking, scrupulous, attentive, punctilious.

All these words can convey careful attention to detail. Also *adroit*, *skillful*, and *masterful* convey a commendable efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

*Fastidious*: it gives more dignity to the trait and steers the connotation away from “obsession”.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to avoid the negative connotation of *pedantic* I'd use

> perfectionist
>   meticulous

Comment: Perfectionist I feel, is still slightly negative. Perhaps I'm being one.

Answer (score 1):

All good suggestions here. I'll just toss in one of my own: *attentive to detail*

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seems to have suggested *conscientious* yet. Just as *pedantic* is nearly always negative, *conscientious* is nearly always positive. To me, *meticulous* is more neutral, sitting somewhere between the two (and as with most neutral words, can be made to sound positive or negative depending on the context it's used in).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is highly concerned about the details of something they could be desribed as being very *particular*.

Answer (score -1):

Those of us who are truly and thoughtfully pondering possible answers to this question are without doubt pedantic/meticulous by nature.