# What is a word like "perfectionist", but without the negative aspects?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that describes people who have high standards for themselves and others and strive to achieve them, but don't expect absolute perfection. They are satisfied with realistic results. As in

> Being a ________ [perfectionist], John spends a great deal of time ensuring the quality of work is above reproach.

I like "perfectionist", but it's too closely associated with words like "persnickety", "hypercritical", "nitpicky", "punctilious", "anal", "pedantic", etc.

I'm finding words like "meticulous", "rigorous", "conscientious", and "thorough", but none of these really fit quite right.

Comment: I don't agree with the idea that ***perfectionist*** has inherently negative connotations - but if people think it *does*, I'd have thought this is an unavoidable consequence of them thinking that the referent itself is undesirable. So any alternative that "means the same" would be tarred with the same brush anyway.

Comment: Closely related: [What is the word(s) for someone who is very particular about the small details of something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59281/what-is-the-words-for-someone-who-is-very-particular-about-the-small-details-o) and [What is a word for someone who wants to be the best at everything they do?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374375/what-is-a-word-for-someone-who-wants-to-be-the-best-at-everything-they-do)

Comment: You could look up 'precisionist' (which is in a rarefied register, however).

Comment: And [Word for someone who pays attention to details](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109928/word-for-someone-who-pays-attention-to-details) and [Is there a single word for “love of quality”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281376/is-there-a-single-word-for-love-of-quality) and [What exactly are the differences between “diligent”, “assiduous” and “sedulous”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94744/what-exactly-are-the-differences-between-diligent-assiduous-and-sedulous)

Comment: There's also this question: [Alternative for “pedantic”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36708/alternative-for-pedantic) As you'll be able to verify, a lot of these questions have identical answers, and  "perfectionst" is among the most popular.  I'm sure you'll find the word that you are looking for.

Comment: @Mari-LouA and all, I searched all of the provided links before I posted, but none of them quite capture the particular shade of meaning I'm after. It seems like such a word does not exist.

Comment: It's always a good idea to include that info in the question, so not one single answer satisfies you? Not even "diligent" nor "assiduous"? Those carry positive connotations, and what about "attentive" or "methodical"? What's wrong with "scrupulous"?

Answer (score 1):

"methodical" or "exacting" or "discriminating" [person]?

I also like "conscientious" and "thorough", though you are concerned that these may not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[detailed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detailed)** or detail oriented:

> marked by abundant detail or by thoroughness in treating small items or parts

Comment: I like "detail orientated" as an answer as it implies that all items are addressed however does not confer an excessive preoccupation with the items being improved to their maximum state.